# Java Swing setIconImage(new ImageIcon(byte[])) doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I have my Java Swing interface of my app and want to set my personal icon in left up corner.

My code:

```
File fimg = new File("D:\\logo.png");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fimg);

WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(data.getData());
setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

This code doesn't work.

If I change this

`new ImageIcon(data.getData()); //ImageIcon(byte[] x)`

with

`new ImageIcon(img); //ImageIcon(Image x)`

work fine.

How to make `ImageIcon(byte[])` to work, in order to store the image as bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SwingTest {

    SwingTest() {

        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException ex) {  ex.printStackTrace();}

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", baos);
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();      }

        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(baos.toByteArray())));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] agrs) {
        new SwingTest();
    }
}
```